# Will standard UK Visitor Visa be granted if the visa at the current country of residence expires?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, ireland

I am resident in the Republic of Ireland. My visa expires in June, 2017. I would like to travel to the UK on the Standard Visitor visa which is valid for 6 months. However my visa at the current country of residence expires in less than 6 months and the next available appointment to renew it is in the end of April, 2017.

I would like to travel my the end of March, 2017. If I apply for the UK visa, will it be rejected on the grounds that my current visa in my country of residence expires in less than 6 months?

Comment: It will not be refused **on that basis alone**, and as long as you have returnability to your home country, then it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89106/will-standard-uk-visitor-visa-be-granted-if-the-visa-at-the-current-country-of-r#comment211976_89106) to answer for the [Answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/2017-maintaining-100-answer-rate-and-trending-our-answers-rank-to-1st)...

> It will not be refused on that basis alone, and as long as you have
>   returnability to your home country, then it's fine.

This answer relies on [Paragraph 28 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk), which says in part...

> ...An application for an entry clearance as a visitor or as a
>   short-term student must be made **to any post designated by the
>   Secretary of State** to accept such applications...

...and there is a British mission in Dublin designated by the Secretary of State to accept entry clearance applications.

And for completeness sake we also look at Appendix V of the same rules, which states in part...

> Applications are decided based on the information provided by the
>   applicant and any other relevant circumstances at the date of
>   decision.

and also...

> (d) provide a **valid travel document**. Where the online application
>   process is not available, the applicant must follow the instructions
>   provided by the local visa post or application centre on how to make
>   an application.

...a travel document is a passport in your case. They are not immediately concerned about what's inside the passport in terms of expiry dates of visas.